# Bootstrap touchspin errors with toFixed() and String()

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I try to use several bootstrap touchspin widgets in parallel. Their minimum and maximum spinner values depend on the value in the neighbouring spinners. Here I encountered error messages (`TypeError: value.toFixed is not a function`) and unexpected behavior with spinner value. Am I doing something wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mini1 = 1.0;
  var maxi1 = 2.0;
  $('#minim').TouchSpin({
      //min: mini1.toFixed(3), //this produces error
      min: mini1,   //this avoids the error 
      max: maxi1,
      step: 0.001,
      initval: 1.5,
      decimals: 3,
      //boostat: 5,
      //maxboostedstep: 1,
      postfix: 'eV',
      //mousewheel: true
    })
    .on('touchspin.on.stopspin', function(e) {
      //var temppi1 = $(this).val(); //gives correct spinner value when min or max are reached during spinning
      var temppi1 = String($(this).val()); //produces erroneous value when min or max are reached during spinning
      $('#labeli1').text("Spinner value: " + temppi1);
    })
    .end();
});
```

```css
.huihai {
  padding-left: 50px;
  width: 240px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-touchspin/3.0.3/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-touchspin/3.0.3/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.js"></script>
<div class='huihai'>
  <label id='labeli1' class="control-label">Min.Spinner:</label>
  <input class="form-control input-sm" id="minim" name="minim" />
</div>
```